# What is the so called "hepatic glucose production"

Tags: physiology

I came across this term in my readings but I do not understand how this works. Can someone direct me to some reference as to what this "hepatic" glucose production is all about?

Comment: Hepatic refers to the liver, which is the predominant location of gluconeogenesis.

Comment: Silly me, I mixed hepatic with haptic (as in haptic feedback) and got totally confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hepatic glucose production" is the gluconeogenesis process (the opposite of the gycolysis process), that is the formation of glucose primarily from lactate and amino acids. This process takes place in the liver's cells and it is regulated by hormones (insulin and glucagon). 
Look [here](http://classes.biology.ucsd.edu/old.web.classes/bibc102.SU04.1/pdf/ch02-glycolysis.pdf) and [here](http://spectrum.diabetesjournals.org/content/17/3/183.full) for a better explanation!